# Binding Image URL with RadImageButton

Tags: c#, data-binding, kendo-ui, telerik, telerik-ajax

I asked on Telerik's site, but there is apparently not enough traffic there to generate answers.

I am trying to convert an asp ImageButton to a RadImageButton because there are some useful features that would make my life a bit easier.  However, the binding for the image URL won't work - at least the way I am doing it.

So this works (both are in the same ListView):

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="im" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>' />
```

But this:

```
<telerik:RadImageButton runat="server" ID="itemImageButton" '>
    <Image Url='<%# Eval("ImgUrl") %>' />
</telerik:RadImageButton>
```

gives me an error something like Telerik.Web.UI.ButtonBase.ButtonImage does not have a DataBinding event.

If someone could point me in the right direction to get this done with the RadImageButton control (if possible), I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was recently facing exactly the same issue. Apparently child objects/properties in some controls are not DataBound-able.

You have to do the binding for the image URL inside the `telerik:RadImageButton` tag itself, so instead of using `<Image Url="" />` section, place it in the `Image-Url` attribute:

```
<telerik:RadImageButton runat="server" ID="itemImageButton" Image-Url='<%# Eval("ImgUrl").ToString() %>'>
</telerik:RadImageButton>
```

You can ommit `.ToString()` part though.

One more "issue" that I've got when switching from `asp:ImageButton` to `telerik:RadImageButton` was the necessity to set the `width` and `height` explicitly. Without it, it didn't work ouf of the box. Image (icon) was malformed, even though it was like 24x24 sized. I ended up setting `width=""` and `height=""` attributes, but adding `CssClass` and using styles should work too.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much!  I like this so much better than binding the item databound event for the listview and handling it there.  For some reason the Image-Url attribute is not showing for me in Intellisense.

I agree on the size thing.  I looked at the output when I found this and saw that instead of adding an image element as I expected, it adds inline styling to create a background-image on the container.  The only way I can think of to resolve it dynamically is to handle it in the data bound event of the RadImageButton or the data container (RadListView in my case).